# Loop through list of text

Tags: python, list, loops, enumerate

I'm trying to write a code in **Python** that iterates through a list of text (events) as following:

```
ln  pid description
1   23  failure in node 5
2   23  restart node 5
3   26  check node 5
4   30  fault alarm in node 10
5   23  finish
..  ..  ..
```

I want the algorithm to check first if the line has the word 'failure' in a node (for example: node 5)  of a process id (pid, say 23) in it and then from there it iterates through the next lines to check for another pid=26 that asks for the same node 5 and *before* the pid 23 'finish' (line 5). Example:
`

```
for line in text:
    if 'failure' in line:
        ... (a loop to check the rest of line for another pid that accesses the same node before the current pid 'finish')
```

`

I tried to use enumerate of the text line indices but I didn't figure out how to iterate from the next line after the line that contains 'failure'. I'm thinking of a while loop that start to iterate through the next lines of text until it finds a line of the same pid and it contains the word 'finish'.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
with open('events.txt') as f:
    failed_node = None
    while True:
        try:
            pid, *msg, node = next(f).split()
            if 'finish' in msg:
                failed_node = None
                continue
            if failed_node is not None:
                if node == failed_node:
                    print(f"{pid=} references {failed_node=}")
            if 'failure' in msg:
                failed_node = node
                print(f"{failed_node=}")
            # print(pid, msg, node)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

with an input file of

```
23  failure in node 5
23  restart node 5
26  check node 5
30  fault alarm in node 10
23  finish
43  failure in node 7
43  restart node 5
46  check node 7
40  fault alarm in node 10
43  finish
```

produces

```
failed_node='5'
pid='23' references failed_node='5'
pid='26' references failed_node='5'
failed_node='7'
pid='46' references failed_node='7'
```

Note: I have removed the line numbers form the file, you can always put them back in.

I am not sure your descriptions tells the whole story. I have done what you have asked, but you might want something more sophisticated, e.g. to keep looking for references to failed nodes even after the first `finish`, i.e. to have them mixed.
In such case, you need to keep a set of the failed nodes, not just the last one (I would scan the whole file once first, then apply the business logic).

At least it gives you a hint on how you can proceed. All the best